# SSRS - multi-value parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

I've got a relatively huge table with `customer ID` s and I'm trying to create an SSRS report where I would be able to pass in a multi-value string to my `@CustomerID` parameter.

For example, two separate customer id's:

`'1212121, 3242342'`.

The question is whether there is any way to set up my parameter so that I can type in my `CustomerID`'s, instead of having to select from a huge drop down list with hundreds of `CustomerID`'s.

Comment: Why would you want to let your users enter these numbers? Do they know the `CustomerID`s by heart?

Comment: I'm short, yes, the end user will have to have CustomerID's before hand.

Answer (score 2):

You **can type directly** into a multi-value parameter. To add more then one entry by hitting Shift+Enter after each entry. Each entry will appear on a separate line. There is no need to add commas.

However this is not a great way of doing things as you are expecting users to know ids.

What I normally do is use two parameters.

The first parameter (called say `@custSearch`)  is a simple plain text parameter.

The second parameter is  populated from a dataset with a query something like this...

```
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName 
    FROM myCustomerTable
    WHERE Customername like '%' + @custSearch + '%'
```

So, the user types a partial match into the first parameter which filters the second one down to only matching customers.